# Передача значения в сниппет

Tags: php, modx

sgController(DocLister) — в шаблоне элемента вызываю самописный сниппет с параметром

```
[[library_prev? &v='[+introtext+]']]
```

сам код сниппета

```
<?php
$replText = $v;
echo mb_strimwidth("$replText", 0, 10, "...");
```

Но в результате получаю пустоту либо просто вывод introtext если писать

```
echo $v;
```

Почему значение не приравнивается к строке или что-то есть ещё?

Вызыв сниппета:

```
[[sgController? 
    &sgOrderBy=`sg_id DESC`
    &thumbSnippet=`phpthumb &thumbOptions=w=200&h=350&zc=1`
    &tpl=`@CODE: <div class="col-4"> <h3>[+pagetitle+]</h3> [+images+] <p>[[library_prev? &v='[+introtext+]']]</p> </div>`
    &sgOuterTpl=`@CODE:[+wrapper+]`
    &sgRowTpl=`@CODE:<img src="[+thumb.sg_image+]" class="img-thumbnail" alt="[+e.sg_title+]" title="[+e.sg_description+]">`
    &sgDisplay=`1`
]]
```

Comment: Это evo, я его не знаю, но вы кавычки не перепутали с апострофом у вас ' стоит вместо `

Comment: У меня идет вызов сниппета в сниппете, поэтому и кавычки вместо апострофа

Answer (score 0):

Сниппет `library_prev` вызывается, в вашем случае, со значением аргумента равным  `[+introtext+]`, т.к. интерполяция значений плейсхлдеров (и специальных тегов текущего документа), в генерируемой странице, происходит на более позднем этапе.

Ваш сниппет будет возвращать результат - строку со значением `[+introtex`, которую вы и будете видеть в результатах работы `DocLister`.

Вам нужно, внутри вашего сниппета, получать значение плейсхолдера `introtext` c использованием MODx API.

Ваш сниппет я бы переписал так:

```
<?php
$replText = $modx->getPlaceholder($v);
return mb_strimwidth($replText, 0, 10, "...");
```

И вызывал бы так: `[[library_prev? &v='introtext']]`

Comment: В таком случае ничего не выводится

Comment: покажите ваши параметры вызова `DocLister`'a

Comment: [[sgController? 
     &sgOrderBy=`sg_id DESC`
     &thumbSnippet=`phpthumb`
     &thumbOptions=`w=200&h=350&zc=1`
     &tpl=`@CODE:
     <div class="col-4">
      <h3>[+pagetitle+]</h3>
      [+images+]
      <p>[[library_prev? &v='[+introtext+]']]</p>
     </div>
     ` 
     &sgOuterTpl=`@CODE:[+wrapper+]`
     &sgRowTpl=`@CODE:<img src="[+thumb.sg_image+]" class="img-thumbnail" alt="[+e.sg_title+]" title="[+e.sg_description+]">`
     &sgDisplay=`1`
    ]]